# How to add a link to a text in a facebook flash template?

Tags: xml, facebook, flash

I have bought a facebook flash template from themeforest. In the XML file, there's one link which works.
It's

```
<A HREF="MAILTO:xyz@gmail.com"><font letterSpacing="0"><U>xyz@gmail.com</U></font></A>
```

But when I try to add something like

```
<A HREF="http://www.gmail.com"><font letterSpacing="0"><U>gmail.com</U></font></A>
```

it doesn't work? Can somebody help me out on this? I've tried googling, but that didn't really help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`MAILTO:` is a generic command to open an email client (program) on your operating system. For example either in my browser address bar or (in Windows, using **START** button and click **RUN**) I can paste `MAILTO:xyz@gmail.com` and either technbique opens Outlook Email ready to send an email.

Changing from `MAILTO:` to some web address doesnt do anything because that button setup wasn't designed to open a new tab with some link, only it triggers some email program installed on your computer.

Did you get an **.FLA** with this theme? If so you need to edit the code and re-compile the FLA to make a new **.SWF** that knows to open a new window when button is clicked. If you don't know Flash programming then ask someone near to help you or even send request to theme author (I'm sure he listens to paying customers).